# Yii pagination not working getting error from js

Tags: ajax, yii, pagination

I have my project on a subdomain and the pagination it works perfectly the same code (exactly the same) on my localhost it doesn't.
I checked the ajax url from localhost:

```
http://myproject.domain.ro/mymodule/payments/index/yt0/Filter/FitnessSubscriber%5Buser_name%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Buser_id%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Bcity%5D/1/FitnessSubscriber%5Bgym_id%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Bab_name%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Babtype_id%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Bhas_companion%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Bcontribution%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Bmonth%5D/4/FitnessSubscriber%5Byear%5D/2015/FitnessSubscriber%5Bpaid%5D//FitnessSubscriber_page/2?ajax=subscribers
```

and from the subdomain:

```
http://myproject.domain.ro/mymodule/payments/index/yt0/Filter/FitnessSubscriber%5Buser_name%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Buser_id%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Bcity%5D/1/FitnessSubscriber%5Bgym_id%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Bab_name%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Babtype_id%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Bhas_companion%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Bcontribution%5D//FitnessSubscriber%5Bmonth%5D/4/FitnessSubscriber%5Byear%5D/2015/FitnessSubscriber%5Bpaid%5D//FitnessSubscriber_page/2?ajax=subscribers
```

As you can see there are the same, but in localhost I got this error message from js:

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

I don't understand the same code, same project on localhost it does not work. Can you give me some idea?

Comment: any weird idea are welcome :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain